# Servlets and synchronization

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, synchronization

Servlets runs in several threads, so my question is:

If I have a lot of servlets which call some utility class (DbUtils, for example

```
Connection c = DbUtils.getConnection();
//....some action with db here
```

should I assume additional actions for synchronization inside DbUtils?

Actually I'd like to inherit HttpServlet into something like DatabaseInvokerServlet:

`public abstract class DatabaseInvokerServlet extends HttpServlet`

with methods:

```
public abstract void getResultSets(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
private AbstractUser currentUser;
private HttpServletRequest request;
private HttpServletResponse response;
protected void processData() {}
protected void afterRequestProcessed() throws ServletException, IOException {}
protected void beforeRequestProcessed() throws ServletException, IOException {}

protected void execute() {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        c = DbUtils.getConnection();
        getResultSets(c);
        processData();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return request;
}

public HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public AbstractUser getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");


    this.request = request;
    this.response = response;
    this.currentUser = (AbstractUser) request.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser");

}
```

Then I'd just inherit my DatabaseInvokerServlet to new servlets to do custom stuff. The reason is not to copy-paste database invoke block with try-catch-finally in a lot of places.

But as I can see such approach won't work because of synchronization issues. Am I right?

Comment: Please post the code of DbUtils.getConnection();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the DbUtils creates the connection in the same thread, like as:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

Then it's threadsafe.

But if the connection is a class variable, like as:

```
private static Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return connection;
}
```

Then it is definitely not threadsafe because the same connection will be shared among all threads. Also when it's closed in a thread, all subsequent threads won't be able to use the connection because it's not open anymore. Also when it's never closed, the DB will timeout the connection sooner or later, usually after a few hours, and your application won't work anymore because the connection is not open anymore.

---

As to the servlet,

```
public abstract class DatabaseInvokerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private AbstractUser currentUser;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    // ...
}
```

it's *definitely* not threadsafe. You're assigning the current user, request and response as instance variables. From each servlet class, there is only one instance during the application's lifetime. This instance is shared among all visitors/sessions throughout the entire application's lifetime. Each HTTP request operates in a separate thread and uses the same instance.

Imagine two simultaneous visitors: visitor A will set the current user, request and response. The DB process however takes a long time. Before the response of visitor A has returned, visitor B calls the same servlet and thus the current user, request and response will be overriden. Then, the query of visitor A finishes and wants to write to the response, it is instead writing to the response of visitor B! Visitor B sees the result of the query of visitor A and visitor A sees nothing on his screen!

You should never assign request/session-specific data as instance variable of the servlet. You should keep them method (thread) local.

```
public abstract class DatabaseInvokerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        AbstractUser currentUser = request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        // Keep the variables in the method block! 
        // Do not assign them as instance variable!
    }
}
```

---

As to the complete picture, this approach is clumsy. The database access layer should have nothing to do with servlets. It should operate in its own standalone classes which you could just construct/invoke in every other Java class, any servlet class, or a normal application with `main()`, or whatever. You should not have any single line of `java.sql.*` imports in your servlet classes (expect of maybe `SQLException` if it is not abstracted away). You should not have any single line of `javax.servlet.*` imports in your database classes.

#### See also:

- [Servlet instantiation and (session) variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)
- [Basic DAO tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the utility class has state (example: class or instance variables) most probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

If I guess right the DBUtils is returning new instance for each call of getConnection(). And as the DBUtils class is a utility class so it shouldn't be maintaining any state. In this scenario no you dont need any addition efforts for synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets runs in several threads.

```
The J2EE spec says there is only one instance per servlet class running in one web container for non single thread servlet.
```

Servlet 2.3 specs

> A servlet container may send
>   concurrent requests through the
>   service method of the servlet. To
>   handle the requests the developer of
>   the servlet must make adequate
>   provisions for concurrent processing
>   with multiple threads in the service
>   method.

Synchronisation in servlet.

```
Never have an member variable in a servlet, it is not thread safe.
```